# awk swapping first two fields gives weird bug

Tags: unix, awk

I'm playing with *awk* and I'm trying to swap the first two fields of a file, like so:

```
awk -F : '/cjares/{temp=$1; $1=$2; $2=temp; print}' /etc/passwd
```

However, the output is not right. These are the two outputs, one without swapping the fields, the second after swapping the fields:

```
x cjares 3158 115 Caleb Timothy Jares,256 Avery Hall,2-7763 /home/ugrad/cjares /bin/tcsh
cjares:x:3158:115:Caleb Timothy Jares,256 Avery Hall,2-7763:/home/ugrad/cjares:/bin/tcsh
```

It replaces all semicolons with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk, the default  output field separator (OFS) is a space " ". You can change it:

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFS=":"} /cjares/{temp=$1; $1=$2; $2=temp; print}' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you're not going to change the value of $0 magically by re-assigning $1 and $2.
You need to tell awk exactly what you want to print here, explicitly.

That means you're going to need to explicitly regenerate the line with

print $2, ":", $1, ":", $3, ":"...

or use printf in a similar manner.

sed may be a slightly better bet here -- you could just swap the first two fields using a regular expression replacement. Alternatively, you could do the same thing in awk using the sub or gsub functions, but that is probably more painful.

BTW, you probably want a space between the /cjares/ and the action.

Comment: First, how do I re-generate the line?
Second, does the space matter, or is it just 'proper'? I was just typing in one-liners, I had no intention of making them pretty.

Comment: I solved it using awk like so: `awk '{printf $2,$1; for(i=3;i<NF;i++) printf ":%s",$i; printf "\n"}' file`, but I'm looking into sed as well. Very interesting. I'm still kind of curious why awk replaces the semicolons with spaces in $0 when I edit $1 or $2.

Comment: Because the default output field separator is space. You could change that to : if you wished. See the awk documentation.